# Call Same Function Present in Various Classes based on String Input in JAVA

Tags: java

Is there any way in JAVA to call the same function which might be present in multiple classes based on the string input we may get from the user during runtime.

e.g.:

```
Class Apple{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Apple");
    }
}
Class Banana{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Banana");
    }
}
```

So, if we get a user input as A we need to call the print() function in the Apple class or else call the print() method from the Banana or any other class based on the inputs we get from the user.

Comment: Just use the good old `switch` statement (or `if else` if there are only a few cases)? Theoretically you could use reflection for that as well but I recommend against that.

Comment: You could do an interface (e.g. `Printable`) which defines the abstract method `print()` and make your classes implement that interface and call the print method on the interface.

Comment: btw.; `class` is lower case in java

Comment: @Amongalen in my case i have some 50-60 odd classes so using the switch case is not a good approach for that hence looking for some better ways to address the same.

Comment: @mexicomanni you would still need to find one of x classes on which to call that method based on string.

Comment: @mexicomanni print is just an example to represent a function call, in practice the function is intended for something else.

Comment: @Amongalen When getting the user input a you make an instance of Apple and else of Banana like this: ` Printable a = new Apple();
        Printable b = new Banana();
        
        a.print();
        b.print();`

Comment: @DwijSheth The name `Printable` also was just an example. You can call the interface how ever you want...

Comment: @mexicomanni which brings us to my first comment, "Just use the good old `switch` statement (or `if else` if there are only a few cases)". Considering OP got 50-60 classes that will be a huge switch.

Comment: @mexicomanni Even if i use the Interface but still how to decide upon the slection of the class provided switch cases and if else is not a good practice in my case.